# How to get this equalize image filter effect with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js

[image]

To this effect
[image]

I have tried with image-js package but it seems not working, is any library which could get this same effect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't CSS filters be a better option?

Comment: @rguttersohn but I am not sure what are those properties I need to set over there

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter, 
https://cssgenerator.org/filter-css-generator.html

Comment: Check out the above links, but honestly unless you need to dynamically add this to images uploaded by a client, why not just add this effect using a photo editing software of some sort?

Comment: I want this to be added to uploaded images, or just any url passing as a query param, but css doesn't work at all